How can I create a circle bubble with border in Flutter CustomPainter?
The following is a reference.
How can I create a border-only bubble with CustomPainter?
But what I want to achieve is a balloon for the circle. The image will be as follows.

If implemented as follows, they will be separated and drawn as shown in the example.
final path = Path();

// create circle
final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2 - 10);
final radius = size.width / 2;
path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius));

// create tip
path.moveTo(center.dx - 10, center.dy + radius);
path.lineTo(center.dx, center.dy + radius + 12);
path.lineTo(center.dx + 10, center.dy + radius);
path.close();

// draw path
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
canvas.drawPath(path, borderPaint);


This may be a rudimentary question, but please answer.

Added code for above shape. Hope it helps.

Was the answer provided helpful to you?

@DroidFlutter Thank you so much for your help. I have taken this as a reference. In the meantime, I have included my own implementation in my response for your reference.

You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. Your own implementation sounds great - Sure! I’d be happy to check it out.

I was able to implement it in my own way and share it with you.Better.I'm sure there is a better way.If you have a better way, please let me know.
class BorderBubblePainter extends CustomPainter {
  BorderBubblePainter({
    this.color = Colors.red,
  });

  final Color color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final width = size.width;
    // Equivalent to width since it is circular.
    // Define a variable with a different name for easier understanding.
    final height = width;
    const strokeWidth = 1.0;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final triangleH = height / 10;
    final triangleW = width / 8;

    // NOTE: Set up a good beginning and end.
    const startAngle = 7;
    // NOTE: The height is shifted slightly upward to cover the circle.
    final heightPadding = triangleH / 10;

    final center = Offset(width / 2, height / 2);
    final radius = (size.width - strokeWidth) / 2;

    final trianglePath = Path()
      ..moveTo(width / 2 - triangleW / 2, height - heightPadding)
      ..lineTo(width / 2, triangleH + height)
      ..lineTo(width / 2 + triangleW / 2, height - heightPadding)
      ..addArc(
        Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius),
        // θ*π/180=rad
        (90 + startAngle) * pi / 180,
        (360 - (2 * startAngle)) * pi / 180,
      );

    canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}


usage
class BubbleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const BubbleWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  static const double _width = 100.0;
  static const double _height = 108.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: _width,
          height: _height,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: BorderBubblePainter(),
          ),
        ),
        Transform.translate(
          offset: const Offset(
            0,
            -(_height - _width) / 2,
          ),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            size: 16,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Try below code with Stack and CustomPainter. Change offset values as your requirement.
          Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset(0, -8), child: VShape(50, Colors.red)),
                  ],
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(0, -5),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 170,
                        height: 170,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset(0, -8),
                          child: VShape(40, Colors.white)),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),

Here is the 'V' shape CustomPainter class
class VShape extends StatelessWidget {
  double size = 0;
  Color color;
  VShape(this.size, this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      size: Size(size, size), // Set the size of the canvas
      painter: VShapePainter(color),
    );
  }
}

class VShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  Color color;
  VShapePainter(this.color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color // Color of the reverse V shape
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    // Create the path for the reverse V shape
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0); // Top left point
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height); // Bottom point
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0); // Top right point
    path.close(); // Close the path

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); // Draw the path
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false; // No need to repaint unless something changes
  }
}

